# Traduccion de leaflet routing

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Estoy intentado traducir el componente leaflet routing. Actualmente mi código es el siguiente. Con la instrucción **language:'sp'** no funciona del todo bien ya que **solo me traduce el formulario pero no las instrucciones** de la ruta. Se que debo usar formatter, pero lo he probado en varios sitios y no funciona nunca. Cuando lo pongo el mapa no se muestra

```
const createRoutingControl = () => {
L.Routing.control({      
  router: L.Routing.mapbox(config.features.routing.key),      
  plan: new (L.Routing.Plan.extend({
    createGeocoders: function () {
      let container = L.Routing.Plan.prototype.createGeocoders.call(this)
      let reverseRoute = createButton('&#8593;&#8595;', container)
      let copyToClipboard = createButton('5', container, true)       

      return container
    }
  }))([], {
    geocoder: geocoder,
    language: 'sp'
  }),
  units: config.features.routing.units,
  showAlternatives: true,
  autoRoute: true,
  routeWhileDragging: true,      
}).addTo(map)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

El truco esta en `language: 'es'`

```js
var map = L.map('map');

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
    attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
}).addTo(map);

var router = L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(-34.60, -58.37),
        L.latLng(-34.57, -58.42)
    ],
    language: 'es', 
    routeWhileDragging: true
}).addTo(map);
```

```css
.map {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-routing-machine@latest/dist/leaflet-routing-machine.js"></script>

<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Tu solución es correcta pero no para mi código.El truco es language: 'es' si, pero donde debería añadirlo en mi codigo para que que traduzca las instrucciones?

Comment: De nada @ABT, es imposible que pueda probar tu código porque no pusiste un ejemplo mínimo funcional, pero yo probaría ponerlo en la misma posición que lo he hecho en mi ejemplo. por ejemplo entre "autoRoute: true" y  "routeWhileDragging: true";